# jquery function doesn't work in wordpress

Tags: jquery, wordpress, timer

I need to integrate this function into my wordpress and I also need to use multiple events of example and it only works with one. Any advice? Thanks.

```
<div id="example">
<p style="display: block;">3 Hours</p>
<p>2h and 30m</p>
<p>2h</p>
<p>1h and 30m</p>
<p>1h</p>
<p>30min</p>
<p>Started</p>
</div>

Jquery
$(document).ready(function(){ 

$("#example p:first").css("display", "block");

jQuery.fn.timer = function() {
    if(!$(this).children("p:last-child").is(":visible")){
        $(this).children("p:visible")
            .css("display", "none")
            .next("p").css("display", "block");
    }
    else{
        $(this).children("p:visible")
            .css("display", "none")
        .end().children("p:first")  
            .css("display", "block");
    }
} // timer function end

window.setInterval(function() {
    $("#example").timer();
}, 50);
```

});

Comment: what errors do you get ? do you have a link ?

Comment: "I also need to use multiple events of example" not sure i understand this statement but ids must be unique on each page

Comment: What exactly is the problem (I can see several). If jQuery was included by Wordpress the proper way, it would be in no-conflict mode, and you should be using `jQuery(function($) { ... });` instead of `$(document).ready`, and `.next("p")` would of course never be visible as long as it's parent is hidden etc.

Comment: I tried jquery(function($) {..} before I posted here.

Comment: Even with the proper case `jQuery(function($) { ... });` ? Open the console and check for errors.

Comment: @roasted what I meant is that I want to use it with let's say : one event must start from 6 hours , other from 3 and a half, other from 5 hours and change from 15 min to 15 min .. I'm sorry it's after 2 AM here and I'm kinda tired.

Comment: @abu http://jsbin.com/acoxef/1/edit

Comment: How would you know if 6 hours has passed, only way that works is if the user keeps the browser open on your page for 6 hours, as javascript has no concept of state outside the browser? JSBin is'nt exactly Wordpress, but you did'nt include jQuery there either!

Comment: @melbourne may be you should focus on explaining your need, like this we can understand better the way you coded your script

Comment: @adeneo really? stop asking this dumb questions. There is a timer in the function 50 if you cannot see it. after that time passes it shows another <p> from the html which is not displayed. So it goes like this: shows 2 hours first after 50 or whatever I decide to put there it shows 1 and half or whatever I decide to put there and so on and so on.

Comment: @melbourne - I don't think the question is stupid. There is no concept of state, so if I leave your page, either by refreshing (F5), going to another tab or just closing the browser, that time will restart again. 50 in your timer function is 0.05 seconds so it will all pass by so fast you won't even see it ?

Answer (score 0):

add this to your functions.php

```
<?php 
if (!is_admin()) 
    add_action("wp_enqueue_scripts", "my_jquery_enqueue", 11);
function my_jquery_enqueue() {
    wp_deregister_script('jquery');
    wp_register_script('jquery', "http" . ($_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] == 443 ? "s" : "") . "://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js", false, null);
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
}
?>
```